Natural reduction from partially observable Markov decision process planning to reconfiguration
Suppose I want to prove the PSPACE-completeness of reconfiguration by reducing partially observable Markov decision process (POMDP) planning to it. Is there a known natural / succinct reduction from exact POMDP planning to reconfiguration?
Seeing as one of the problems involves probabilities expressed as real numbers, I suspect the answer is no in general. But what if the probabilities are simple fractions?
